# How to implement multiple tomcat instances for single apache server without load-balancing?

Tags: apache, tomcat, cluster-computing, application-server

I have a VM-ware machine which consists of 2 diff virtual machines and each machine is comprised of one apache-server and its corresponding tomcat-server-instance.
In case, if one of tomcat-instance goes dead, both apache-servers should point to only the remaining alive tomcat-instance, this can be easily achieved with clustering.
But I do not wish to include load-balancing in the scenario, only if tomcat-instance in any of the machines goes dead then only the other one should be pointed by corresponding apache-server. Here please let me know can this be achieved without load-balancing ? and if you think yes, please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for just failover, not load balancing. You can use DNS failover but [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/60553/why-is-dns-failover-not-recommended) covers some of the limitations in detail.